# how to attach a door handle onto wall

Tags: walls, kitchens

I need a light duty rail in my kitchen to hang cleaning clothes just near the sink. After doing my market research, I saw a door handle with a suitable shape, something similar to [this](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/kallroer-handle-stainless-steel-30357003/):

[image]

However it requires screwing from the other side; from my neighbor's flat and with a very long screw, theoretically speaking.

Is there an easy way to attach such a door handle onto kitchen tiles? If it required one screw, it could be done with a plug and a hanger bolt, however I need two points of attachment and the handle cannot be disassembled.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into **towel bars**. They are typically designed with one piece that screws into a wall, using an appropriate screw (into a stud or masonry) or anchor + screw (into a hollow wall) and then a second piece that slips over the part in the wall and tightens with a screw around the edge.

However, it you are really set on a handle that only screws in from behind (which is typical of cabinet and drawer handles), then you can:

- Cut a piece of wood a couple inches tall and slightly wider than the handle
- Paint the wood to match the tile or contrast with it, depending on the tile, trim, cabinets, etc. of the kitchen. *Easier to paint the wood before installation than after installation.*
- Attach the handle to the wood, as if it were a drawer/cabinet front
- Locate two studs and use screws to attach the wood to the wall, or use appropriate heavy-duty anchors + screws to attach the wood to the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no image makes it hard, but I would drill and fit two screws into the wall at the correct spacing. Then cut the heads off the screws and put an epoxy resin type glue into the holes - push onto the screws and support until the glue hardens.